# How to get the data inside a html table cell when clicked on it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I created a html table and filled it dynamically. So I want to **alert** the data inside a cell of the table when i clicked it. Here is the code for the table

JSP

```
<table id="load-opt"></table>
```

I'm filling the data inside dynamically like this

```
var fillTable = function($element, data) {
    var t_head = $("<tr></tr>");
    for(var ind=0; ind<data.length; ind++) {
        //name is the name and desc is the description for each option
        var $option = $("<tr></tr>");
        $option.html("<td>"+name+"</td><td>"+desc+"</td>");
    }
};
```

I tried this but it's not working, it's giving "undefined".

```
var choice = $('table#load-opt tr td');
choice.click(function(){
    alert(choice); // also tried alerting choice.textContent, choice.innerHTML and choice.firstChild
});
```

Comment: Use `$(this).text()`

Comment: use alert($(this)) instead of alert(choice), variable choice is undefined in this scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$(this).text()`  to fetch the data in table cell.
[This is a link.](http://jsfiddle.net/uea8k4ny/)

Answer (score 1):

you are actually trying to alert the 'td' object not value of from that object so you can use following to solve the query.Here i am using on instead of direct click function because of dynamically added data.

```
var choice = $('table#load-opt tr td');
 choice.on('click', function(){
 alert($(this).text());
});
```